# How to set event name and delay time in Envelope?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-messenger

I'm using symfony 4 + enqueue (https://github.com/sroze/messenger-enqueue-transport + https://packagist.org/packages/enqueue/pheanstalk) to run async jobs in beanstalk.

Right now I have:

```
/**
 * @var Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface 
 */
private $eventDispatcher;

$event = new ArticleEvent("test title", "test description");
$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch($event, "article.publish");
```

But I want this job to be processed after a delay.

Documentation brings me to refactor it like:

```
use Enqueue\MessengerAdapter\EnvelopeItem\TransportConfiguration;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope;

$event = new ArticleEvent("test title", "test description");
$transportConfig = (new TransportConfiguration())->setDeliveryDelay(5000);

$this->eventDispatcher->dispatch((new Envelope($event))->with($transportConfig));
```

The problem here is that I don't see where to place event's name (`article.publish`)

(Based on https://github.com/sroze/messenger-enqueue-transport#setting-custom-configuration-on-your-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With messenger you do not have "event names".

You just need to dispatch the appropriate message instance.

If you are publishing an article, instead of having a generic `ArticleEvent` class, build a `PublishArticle` command or an `ArticlePublished` event.

The choice between the two depends on if you are registering an event (something that already happened) or a command (something you want to happen).

[Creating a handler for these messages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#creating-a-message-handler) is as simple as creating a `MessageHandlerInterface` implementing class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

class PublishArticleHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{
    public function __invoke(PublishArticle $message)
    {
        // ... do some work - like publishing the article
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, how then i subscribe to them? i was using getSubscribedEvents() method which uses event names:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html#using-event-subscribers

Comment: If you are using Messenger, you need to create message handlers. Do not look at Event Dispatcher docs, but at Symfony Messenger docs. Like [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html) or [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html).